# Apache http client self signed cert

Tags: java, http, ssl, self-signed

I am trying to make HTTP requests to web services via Apache HTTP client, but I am getting a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I followed below suggestion to test but still getting the same error. Anything I missed?
https://memorynotfound.com/ignore-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient/

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class TestHttpSSL {

    public static void main(String... args)  {

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = createAcceptSelfSignedCertificateClient()) {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://myurl/");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

            httpclient.execute(httpget);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static CloseableHttpClient createAcceptSelfSignedCertificateClient()
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                .build();

        HostnameVerifier allowAllHosts = new NoopHostnameVerifier();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, allowAllHosts);

        return HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question what you want to achieve.

If you need to use self-signed certificate for "https://myurl/", you should provide the truststore with this certificate. The example (assuming that you've placed the certificate to the `resources` folder and assign its path to `certPath` variable and its password to `certPassword`):

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
byte[] certificate = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(certPath));
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificate);
trustStore.load(bis, certPassword.toCharArray());
```

Here, [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is used to convert the input stream to byte array for simplicity, but you can do it manually. You can optionally pass the certificate type to the `getInstance` method instead of using the default one (f.e., `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");`)

Then use the prepared truststore while creating `SSLContext`:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
        .create()
        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
        .build();
```

If, instead, you want to disable the SSL checking completely, you can use [the another strategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustAllStrategy.html) - `TrustAllStrategy`. In this case, you don't need to set up any truststore at all. The example:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
        .create()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy())
        .build();
```

Comment: The `new TrustAllStrategy()` worked for me. Understanding this is not a good idea to do so but at least this is a workaround. Thanks.